How can I rollback entire databricks catalog/database to a point in time
The scenario is:  I've run some defective transformation code over numerous tables in a databricks catalog. I need to restore the whole catalog/database back to a point in time instead of restoring each table individually. It this functionality available in databricks?
I know you can do this easily in Snowflake but does databricks have same functionality?

Databricks saves versions at the table level, and can only restore tables, not the entire database.
You can run the script below to restore all tables one by one:
restore_timestamp = "2024-06-30 00:00:00"
db_name = "dwh"
tables = spark.sql(f"show tables in {db_name}").collect()
for t in tables:
    table_name = t["tableName"]
    print(table_name)
    restore_sql = f"RESTORE TABLE {db_name}.{table_name} TO TIMESTAMP AS OF '{restore_timestamp}';"
    spark.sql(restore_sql)

